# Trying to configure gunicorn

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have been following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) to deploy my django project on Digital Ocean. I am trying to configure [gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04#creating-systemd-socket-and-service-files-for-gunicorn).

My project structure looks similar to this:

[image]

On my `settings.py` I use `DEBUG=False`

I create the gunicorn.socket and gunicorn.service.

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=someuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/someuser/myproject
ExecStart=/home/someuser/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          Myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I  start and enable the Gunicorn socket:

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket 
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
```

Check the status of the process to find out whether it was able to start:

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket
```

This is what I get and then it returns to the command line.

```
Failed to dump process list, ignoring: No such file or directory
β—� gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (listening) since Sat 2019-05-04 23:12:03 UTC; 13s ago
   Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket

May 04 23:12:03 myproject systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.
```

Next, I check for the existence of the gunicorn.sock  file within the /run directory:

```
file /run/gunicorn.sock
/run/gunicorn.sock: socket
```

It seems that a file or directory doesn't exist, but it doesn't provide any more details. The gunicorn.sock seems to exist.

I am familiar with Python but not with servers and deploying so I am at a loss here.

I have successfully followed the similar tutorial for Ubuntu 16.04 a few months ago, but now I keep hitting issues.

Answer (score 1):

I know, that's old question, but...
I haved some error. In my case wrong WorkingDirectory and application with modul wsgi. I think that's error in "myproject.wsgi:application"

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an issue with your usage of `systemd`. You need to refer to the name of the service in your calls to `systemctl`, not the socket as you're doing. In your case the service will be called `gunicorn` because you've named your systemd unit file as `gunicorn.service`.

```
systemctl enable gunicorn
systemctl start gunicorn
```

Comment: Do you know how can I get more details about the error: "Failed to dump process list, ignoring: No such file or directory" ?